# Center UIActivityIndicatorView in a UiView on device orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've read nearly everything related to this topic already, but literally nothing works.

When `_spinnerContainer` appears, `_spinner` is displayed in the middle of it, but when device is rotated, `_spinnerContainer` rotates as expected and `_spinner` freezes in the middle of old `_spinnerContainer`'s position.

I believe that it should be something really trivial.

Any help?

Thanks!

```
_spinnerContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.rectForView];
_spinnerContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.35];
_spinnerContainer.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
_spinnerContainer.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_spinnerContainer.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
_spinnerContainer.clipsToBounds = NO;
_spinnerContainer.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

_spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
_spinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
_spinner.center = _spinnerContainer.center;
[_spinner startAnimating];
[_spinnerContainer addSubview:_spinner];
```

Comment: How does `_spinnerContainer` ever get into the interface? Your code makes no sense without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete this:

```
_spinnerContainer.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

Comment: thank you very much! You are exactly to the point!
I'm like a bear: 2x2 = 5 and I nearly broken my head =)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that this code:

```
_spinner.center = _spinnerContainer.center;
```

...means "put the spinner in the center of the spinner container". It doesn't. It makes no sense, in fact, because `_spinnerContainer.center` is a position somewhere in the spinner container's *superview*, and in the superview's coordinate system — whereas `_spinner.center` needs to be positioned relative to *its* superview, i.e. relative to the spinner container's own *internal* coordinate system (also known as its `bounds`).

So, although you say that "When `_spinnerContainer` appears, `_spinner` is displayed in the middle of it," in fact this more or less coincidence. Your code does not even construct the *initial* interface correctly, so it is not surprising that it doesn't work after rotation.

In my personal view, the simplest solution here is to throw your code away and use auto layout constraints to position these views. Auto layout has the advantage that it describes exactly what should happen regardless of rotation.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Your explanations are really interesting - I'm not an iOS development. Decided to start from Dmitry's solution and it worked like a charm =)

Comment: Excellent! But you still should not be setting the center of a view to the center of its superview; that will appear to work only under very rare circumstances (and you stumbled on one). In my view, learning auto layout and doing what you're doing with constraints is a lot simpler, even if it appears to be more code to begin with.